# Redraw in TabControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Не могу понять почему не происходит перерисовка иконки в `tabControl1`, в чем ошибка?

> Где то в коде `ResizeRedraw = true;`

```
        private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int Index = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
        Rectangle r = tabControl1.GetTabRect(Index);
        Rectangle closeButton = new Rectangle(r.Right - 20, r.Top + 2, 16, 16);
        if (this.tabControl1.TabPages[Index].Name != "tabPage7")
        {
            if (closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                ValueConfiguration.MouseLeave = true;
                Bitmap NewBitmap = new Bitmap(imageList1.Images[29]);
                tabControl1.DrawToBitmap(NewBitmap, closeButton);
                tabControl1.TabPages[Index].DrawToBitmap(NewBitmap, closeButton);
            }
            if (!closeButton.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                ValueConfiguration.MouseLeave = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Я не вижу у вас кода перерисовки иконки. У вас создаётся новое изображение, в него выводится `TabControl`, потом туда же выводится выбранная `TabPage` методом `DrawToBitmap`. После чего ссылка на это изображение теряется.

Answer (score 1):

Код по отрисовке следует перенести в обработчик события `tabControl1.DrawPaint`, а в `tabControl1_MouseMove` вызывать `tabControl1.Invalidate()`. 
Также нужно установить свойство `tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`

Comment: tabControl1.Paint  данное событие не определено для tabControl1 как я могу его использовать  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.paint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: действительно, так. Пардон. Ответ исправил